# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli)?

Tags: java

Solo me sucede con proyetos maven, he aprobado a usar la opcion de clean & builder para el proyecto pero me sigue dando el mismo error

[image: El error completo]

[image: Este es el archivo pom.xml]

Comment: Hola Santi, el código va como texto, no como imagen, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, y mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: Tratá de subir el código de la clase `PROG07_Ejerc` así te podemos ayudar.